# Is there a way to tell matplotlib to loosen the zoom on the plotted data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data plotted which includes some limits on each subplot: [image: aerodynamic angles with limits] Both axes have the limits, but since the data fits so nicely within the limits on the second plot, the limits themselves set the boudaries for the y-axis, making them invisible.

To make them visible, I could do something like this:

`axes.set_ylim(1.1*lowerLimit,1.1*upperLimit)`

where `lowerLimit` and `upperLimit` are the data used to generate the limits in the first place, but I am wondering if matplotlib has a mechanism to tell it to not be so zealous in it's automatic setting of the limits.  The solution I have now also has the limitation that if the data deviates from the boundaries, it risks going outside the lines, so I searched for a complement to `set_ylim()` which would tell me what the limits are, somehting like `get_ylim()` but it does not seem to exist in [the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axis_api.html).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Although It is not documented, I attempted `get_ylim()` and it worked, so I was able to scale up the limits and re-apply them with `set_ylim()` so I have a decent workaround for now, but it would be nice if I there were a better way.  I suppose I could write a little function that would do this to any set of axes I passed to it.

Comment: FWIW it does seem to be documented: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=_ylim#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim

Comment: Rats! I was looking in the wrong place, The old axis vs. axes confusion. Apparently I need to spend some more time to understand the distinctions.

Comment: I have this problem a lot.  I'd love to be able to set some default percent margin for *all* plots.  Is there a way?

Comment: @tcaswell, What is the criteria for selecting which question is the original and which is the duplicate?  This Question seems to pre-date the other question by over a year.

Comment: It does, but the answer on the other one is better.

Comment: @tacaswell, `margins` doesn't seem to work with subplots (the question context), at best it adds space around the set of suplots. It's too bad you closed this question based on a wrong alternative, and it's also too bad you give preference to a newer question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to your request for a function to change the y-axis limits, would this suit your purposes?:

```
def larger_axlim( axlim ):
    """ argument axlim expects 2-tuple 
        returns slightly larger 2-tuple """
    axmin,axmax = axlim
    axrng = axmax - axmin
    new_min = axmin - 0.1 * axrng
    new_max = axmax + 0.1 * axrng
    return new_min,new_max
...
ax.set_ylim( larger_axlim( ax.get_ylim() ) )
...
```

Documentation: [`get_ylim()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html?highlight=_ylim#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim)

Comment: That would do the job in the most elegant manner in lieu of  a built-in feature.

Comment: what if ymin is 0?  Don't you really want something like `ymin - 0.1 * (ymax-ymin)`?

Comment: Thanks, endolith. I incorporated your suggestion.

Comment: this is what `margins` exists to do

Comment: Is there a `margins` property that can be applied to autoscale?  Which `margins` property can we modify to cause autoscale to leave a margin around the data? Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations! This solution is the first one I see which actually works with subplots. Other like `Axes.margins` (proposed when closing this question as duplicate) or `plt.subplots_adjust` don't (or the conditions for them to work are not specified). Documentation for `get_ylim()` [has moved](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim). I voted to reopen this question.