# How to reduce xticks label resolution when showing clock time

Tags: python, matplotlib

The labels on my x-axis show the clock time of the day. Whenever I zoom in on the plot, they look silly with 6 decimals all at 0. I am not at all interested in showing microseconds.

See the xticks labels, before zooming in:
[image]

After zooming in:
[image]

Here's what I have today:

```
ax_average.xaxis_date()
fig_average.autofmt_xdate()
fig_average.tight_layout()
```

How can I make sure that only seconds (or even better minutes) show in the tick labels?

---

Here is a somewhat reduced version of the code that plots the above:

```
# Requires python-matplotlib
import numpy
from pylab import *

raw_data = [
'Apr 20 12:14:36 a b temp_0 = 21.400000',
'Apr 20 12:14:36 a b temp_1 = 17.860000',
'Apr 20 12:14:36 a b temp_3 = 50.350006',
'Apr 20 12:14:51 a b temp_0 = 21.400000',
'Apr 20 12:14:51 a b temp_1 = 17.860000',
'Apr 20 12:14:51 a b temp_3 = 50.350006',
'Apr 20 12:15:06 a b temp_0 = 21.400000',
'Apr 20 12:15:06 a b temp_1 = 17.860000',
'Apr 20 12:15:06 a b temp_3 = 50.250000',
'Apr 20 12:15:21 a b temp_0 = 21.400000',
'Apr 20 12:15:21 a b temp_1 = 17.860000',
'Apr 20 12:15:21 a b temp_3 = 50.250000']

def month_string_to_int(input):
    if (input == 'Jan'):
        return 1
    elif (input == 'Feb'):
        return 2
    elif (input == 'Mar'):
        return 3
    elif (input == 'Apr'):
        return 4
    elif (input == 'May'):
        return 5
    elif (input == 'Jun'):
        return 6
    elif (input == 'Jul'):
        return 7
    elif (input == 'Aug'):
        return 8
    elif (input == 'Sep'):
        return 9
    elif (input == 'Oct'):
        return 10
    elif (input == 'Nov'):
        return 11
    elif (input == 'Dev'):
        return 12
    else:
        print "Error in the month string: %s" % input
        return -1

data = {}
timestamps = {}
for line in raw_data:
    line = line.strip() # strip newline character
    lst = line.split()  # space as separator

    day = datetime.date(2015, month_string_to_int(lst[0]), int(lst[1]))
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(lst[2], "%H:%M:%S").time()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.combine(day, time)

    identifier = lst[5]
    value = float(lst[7])

    if identifier not in data:
        data[identifier] = []
        timestamps[identifier] = []

    data[identifier].append(value)
    timestamps[identifier].append(timestamp)

fig, ax = subplots()
plot(timestamps['temp_0'], data['temp_0'])

ax.xaxis_date()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()

show()
```

The `timestamps` dictionary looks as I expect:

```
In [103]: timestamps
Out[103]: 
{'temp_0': [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 36),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 51),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 6),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 21)],
 'temp_1': [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 36),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 51),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 6),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 21)],
 'temp_3': [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 36),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 14, 51),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 6),
  datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 12, 15, 21)]}
```

The xticks labels look like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to post code to reproduce your graph? It may be worth checking [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) which accepts a format string

Comment: I'll try so have a minimal code example. See my edit though, the time format is ok before I zoom in.

Comment: @EdChum: here comes code. Unfortunately not reduced to its minimal, but hopefully simple enough to quickly get the idea.

Comment: @EdChum: you were right about `DateFormatter`, I just did not know how to use it. I find my answer in "related questions". Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found this:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651367/manually-setting-xticks-with-xaxis-date-in-python-matplotlib).

---

Better yet, as the solution above does not display days anymore when zoomed out:

```
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateFormatter, AutoDateLocator

xtick_locator = AutoDateLocator()
xtick_formatter = AutoDateFormatter(xtick_locator)
xtick_formatter.scaled[30.] = '%d %b'
xtick_formatter.scaled[1.] = '%d %b'
xtick_formatter.scaled[1/24.] = '%d/%m %H:%M'
xtick_formatter.scaled[1/(24.*60.)] = '%d/%m %H:%M'
xtick_formatter.scaled[1/(24.*60.*60.)] = '%d/%m %H:%M:%S'
ax_av.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)
ax_av.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xtick_formatter)
```

[This](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter) helped a lot (although the example with no argument for `AutoDateFormatter` doesn't work for me)

Comment: @EdChum: the problem with that is when I have a measurement that spans several days. Zoomed in the timestamps are good, but when I zoom out, all my ticks are "00:00", instead of showing dates.

Comment: That is useful to know

Comment: @Gauthier Is there a resource page for the formatting codes?

Comment: Old post, but the format codes are the same as those used with [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).