# How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm currently creating many plots and some look great while other need some adjustment.  From below how can I make the hard to see plot line easier to see without having to manually plot them?  I plot 50-100 of these at a time then add them to a pdf report.  I'd like to add space under the line, for example have ylim min limit set to -0.1, but do it automatically.

This one is hard to see plot line:
[image: Hard to see plot line]

This one is easy to see plot line:
[image: Easy to see plot line]

Here is my code for plotting:

```
def plot(chan_data):
'''Uses matplotlib to plot a channel
'''
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 2.5))
x = dffinal['time'].keys()    
ax.plot(x, dffinal[chan_data].values, linewidth=0.4, color='blue')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y - %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator(interval_multiples=True))

lgd1 = ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

f.autofmt_xdate()
ax.set_ylabel(dffinal[chan_data].name)
ax.grid('on')

#I've tried these with no luck
#ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=False)
#ax.set_ymargin(0.5)
#ax.set_autoscaley_on(True)

fname = ".\\plots\\" + chan_data + ".png"
print "Creating: " + fname
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=100, bbox_extra_artist=(lgd1,), bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
return fname
```

Comment: Perhaps the solution proposed in this answer would be acceptable for your use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6230993/42346

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want `margins` [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

ex

```
ax.margins(y=.1)
```

Also see [Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142)