# Create padding within plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt

I'm working on my matplotlibwidget that I've created with QtDesigner.

When i draw my testpoints into my plot, they are mostly arranged at the border or cross the axes. Which does not look very familiar to me.

So my question is, how can i tell matplotlib to add some kind of "inner padding" between plot-border and test points. So for example if my minimum value is "500" i would like to plot the left border at around 400, so there is some margin between the least point and border.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`plt.margins`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.margins) can be used to adjust the automatic padding around your data as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.power(x, 3)

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')

# Create a 5% (0.05) and 10% (0.1) padding in the 
# x and y directions respectively.
plt.margins(0.05, 0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

If you had a minimum value of `500` and wanted the border to be around `400` then you could choose an x-margin percentage of `0.2` as in `plt.margins(0.2, 0.2)`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with subplots (or maybe it adds space around the whole figure, in a proportion which is hard to understand).