# Data points cut off when plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I have a plot where the data points has been cut off, as can be seen in the picture. I need to fix this issue by showing clearly the data points, I have already tried to use ax.margins from previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib) , but it does not change anything on my plot. The following is the code I am using. I guess the ylim might be raising this issue, but if I don't use ylim all my data stays very near to zero axis.

```
def doscatterplot(xcoord,ycoord,labellist,ax=None):
    ax = ax
    ax.scatter(xcoord, ycoord,label=labellist)
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
    ax.legend()
    ax.margins(0.1,y=0.7)
    ax.set_ylim(min(ycoord),max(ycoord))
    ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y',style='sci',scilimits=(-3,-4))
    ax.axhline(y=0, color='g')
    ax.axvline(x=0, color='g')
    ax.set_ylabel('Transversal Resistance [\u03A9]')
    ax.set_xlabel('HCools [T]')
    ax.set_title('Transversal Resistance [\u03A9] vs HCools [T]' )
    return
```

[image]

Comment: As you said, by declaring `ax.set_ylim(min(ycoord),max(ycoord))` you are adjusting the limits of the y axis to the extrema values of `ycoord`, so your output is expected. Add a little margin to both values, for example, with something like `(max(ycoord) -  min(ycoord))/20`.

Comment: I didn't change anything. Is there a way of using yticks instead of ylim that you might know?

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in my comment is to add this extra line of code:

```
dy = (max(ycoord) - min(ycoord))/20
```

to add a little extra space above and below your plotted data (in this case, the 20th part of the range of your data). Change the old line for this one and it should work as you want:

```
ax.set_ylim(min(ycoord) - dy, max(ycoord) + dy)
```

Also, note that you can write greek symbols without resorting to unicode language, try for example

```
ax.set_ylabel(r'Transversal Resistance [$\Omega$]')
```

You can see more information [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html#text-rendering-with-latex).