# setting margins in matplotlib/seaborn with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i'm plotting subplots in matplotlib/seaborn using:

```
plt.figure()
s1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
# plot 1 
# call seaborn here
s2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
# plot 2
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

i am running into the common issue of marker being hidden by the axis ([Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142)). when i try to adjust margins it doesn't work:

```
s1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
s1.margins(0.05)
```

it gives no error but doesn't set margins either.

***here is a complete example:***

```
gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")
s = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
# this does not change the x margins
s.get_axes().margins(x=0.05, y=0.01)
ax = sns.tsplot(time="timepoint", value="BOLD signal",
                unit="subject", condition="ROI",
                err_style="ci_bars",
                interpolate=False,
                data=gammas)
plt.show()
```

in the above, i am trying to make the x-margins bigger, but the `x` argument to `margins()` seems to have no effect. how can this be done?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230627/is-there-a-way-to-tell-matplotlib-to-loosen-the-zoom-on-the-plotted-data?lq=1 has a better answer than the one you link. Does it work for you?  (P.S. - a *complete* small runnable example would be a lot more pleasant to work with. )

Comment: @cphlewis: you are right i added a small complete example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function to add a given fraction of the `x` and `y` ranges to the margin, which makes use of `get_xlim`, `get_ylim`, `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`. Using your minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def add_margin(ax,x=0.05,y=0.05):
    # This will, by default, add 5% to the x and y margins. You 
    # can customise this using the x and y arguments when you call it.

    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()

    xmargin = (xlim[1]-xlim[0])*x
    ymargin = (ylim[1]-ylim[0])*y

    ax.set_xlim(xlim[0]-xmargin,xlim[1]+xmargin)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim[0]-ymargin,ylim[1]+ymargin)

gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")
s = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax = sns.tsplot(time="timepoint", value="BOLD signal",
                unit="subject", condition="ROI",
                err_style="ci_bars",
                interpolate=False,
                data=gammas)

# Check what the original limits were
x0,y0=s.get_xlim(),s.get_ylim()

# Update the limits using set_xlim and set_ylim
add_margin(s,x=0.05,y=0.01) ### Call this after tsplot 

# Check the new limits
x1,y1=s.get_xlim(),s.get_ylim()

# Print the old and new limits
print x0,y0
print x1,y1

plt.show()
```

Which prints:

```
# The original limits
(-0.10101010101010099, 10.1010101010101) (-2.0, 3.0)
# The updated limits
(-0.61111111111111105, 10.611111111111111) (-2.0499999999999998, 3.0499999999999998)
```

And here's the figure this produces:

[image]

Which, when compared to the original figure, clearly has added margins:

[image]

Comment: i added a complete example with ``sns.tsplot`` where this does not work.

Comment: This function still works fine for me. I'll update my example to show it in action on your minimal example.